# Check if string contains only UTF-8 characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to check in python3 if given string contains only **utf-8** characters?

Comment: Do you mean a string or a bytes? As far as I know, utf8 can encode all characters. So if the question is "Can all characters in this string be encoded with utf8?" then the answer should always be "yes". If the question is "Can all of these bytes be interpreted as utf8?", then the question is more interesting.

Comment: Can you suggest an example of a valid string and a invalid string for your needs?

Comment: Are you trying to determine if a group of binary bytes is in valid UTF-8?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about `bytes`, you can do this:

```
data = bytearray([0xF0])

try:
    data.decode("UTF-8", "strict")
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print("Not UTF-8")
else:
    print("UTF-8")
```